# Stop listings going over page breaks

Tags: listings, page-breaking, pandoc, markdown

I am using Pandoc to generate Tex from Markdown. It automatically generates listings when it comes across the appropriate Markdown (code indented four spaces). It then uses the `listings` package to instantiate those listings in Tex. The resulting code is:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
    # java -version
    java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.3.el6_3.1-i386)
    OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
\end{lstlisting}
```

Sometimes these code listings extend across a page break and I'd prefer if they were bumped to the next page if this happens. I've looked around and seen a few suggestions about adding a `minipage` to the listing but since my Tex is being auto-generated via Pandoc it's not clear how I can do that without manually editing the resulting Tex document to add the minipages before and after the lstlistings.

So I am looking for:

1. A way to bump the listings to the next page automatically, or
2. A way to tell LaTex to redefine the lstlisting to have minipages before and after it.

EDIT: I should have added for those unfamiliar with Pandoc that the template it uses to generate Tex is [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to a document preamble? I'm unfamiliar with Pandoc's interface.

Comment: This is the default LaTeX template that Pandoc generates this: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex.

Comment: Line 47-49 designates a condition based on the existence of a listing (I guess). Instead of a single line (48) with `\usepackage{listings}`, use `\usepackage{listings,float}\lstset{float=H}`. Again, since I'm unfamiliar with Pandoc, you'll have to try it.

Comment: You are correct - that enables the `listings` package when you pass the `--listings` option to Pandoc. I've made your change and given that a try but the listings continue to extend over the page break I am afraid. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: The `float` option seem to be specific to an environment, and cannot be set globally. Do you have access to the language settings it uses (`language=bash`)?

Comment: No I don't as far as I can see. Is lstlisting an environment in LaTeX terms (sorry only a recent user of it) and can I globally redefine it to add a float=H? Apologies if I have misunderstood your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: No. I did not. Sorry.

Comment: @AviramSegal: Did you try the package `etoolbox` with `\BeforeEnvironment` and `\AfterEnvironment`? This should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by Werner the normal way to prevent `listings` to do any package breaks is the option `float`. However this can't be done globally without changing the internals of `listing`.

Another hack would be to surround the environment `listings` with a non breakable box. This can be achieved with the facilities of the package `etoolbox` and the provided commands `\BeforeEnvironment` and `\AfterEnvironment`:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{listings}{\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{listings}{\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{\topskip}}
```

Of course instead of `minipage` you can use any other environment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous answers and comments, here is the solution I use with Pandoc 1.15.

Specific command line options :

```
--listings -H header.latex
```

Specific header.latex file content :

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{\topskip}}
```

Comment: I get the following error: ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.